# Validating links in PHP

Tags: php, for-loop

I'm building a broken link checker. So far I've managed to get this to crawl a user specified page for links and then echo a complete list of links, so I know it's finding them. What I need to do now is get it to check each of those links for the HTTP response, (which I can then highlight in some way later).

```
 $html = file_get_contents($_POST['urlInput']);

    $dom = new DOMDocument();
    @$dom->loadHTML($html);

    $xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
    $hrefs = $xpath->evaluate("/html/body//a");

    for ($i = 0; $i < $hrefs->length; $i++) {
            $href = $hrefs->item($i);
            $url = $href->getAttribute('href');
            echo $url.'<br>';
```

This is where my problem starts. The above code will find and echo all links on a page, and I'm trying to figure out how to check each of them. 
The code below doesn't work, but being completely new to PHP I don't understand what it is and/or isn't doing!

```
 get_http_response_code($url);
    }




    function get_http_response_code($url) {
      $headers = get_headers($url);
      return substr($headers[0], 9, 3);
    }

    $get_http_response_code = get_http_response_code($url);

    if ( $get_http_response_code == 200 ) {
      echo "Working!";
    } else {
      echo "Broken!";
    }
```

For now I would just like to find out how to get it to echo working or broken for each link.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you qualify 'it doesn't work' a bit better? Are you getting an error or just the wrong results?

Answer (score 0):

Solution found:

```
<?php

$website = $_POST['urlInput'];

$html = file_get_contents($website);

$website = preg_replace('{/$}', '', $website);

$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTML($html);

$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$hrefs = $xpath->evaluate("/html/body//a");


for ($i = 0; $i < $hrefs->length; $i++) {
        $href = $hrefs->item($i);
        $url = $href->getAttribute('href');

//The following two lines included to handle relative paths

        $url = ltrim($url, '/');
        $url = isAbsoluteUrl($url) ? $url : $website.'/'.$url;

//It then calls this function for each iteration of loop



 get_http_response_code($url);
}


function get_http_response_code($url) {

        $handle = curl_init($url);
        curl_setopt($handle,  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);


        $response = curl_exec($handle);


        $httpCode = curl_getinfo($handle, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
        if($httpCode == 200) {
                echo $url . ": <span style='color: green'>ok</span> <br>";
        } else if($httpCode == 301 || $httpCode == 302) {
                echo $url . ": <span style='color: orange'>Redirected</span> <br>";
        } else {
                echo $url . ": <span style='color: red'>Nook</span> <br>";
        }



        curl_close($handle);
}

function isAbsoluteUrl($url)
    {
        if (strpos($url, 'http://') !== false || strpos($url, 'https://') !== false) {
                return true;
              }

              return false;
    }

?>
```